# How do I use a do while loop to reverse a circular linked list in Java?

Tags: java, list, while-loop

I am currently creating a pretty standard take on a circular linked list, and want to reverse it. If it is given 3 nodes Purple, Happy, and Rabbit, it should return Rabbit -> Happy -> Purple. Right now, for some reason, it prints Happy -> Purple -> Purple. I think there is a problem with the logic in my do while loop, as I am pretty new to linked lists.

I did not include my other classes for defining node functions since they're pretty long with other irrelevant code and I know that the problem is not there (printing forward works fine). Any pointers are appreciated, and if anything else is needed let me know!

```
public void reverse() {
        String result = " ";
        Node current = head;
        if (current != null) {
            do {
                current = current.prev;
                result += current + ", ";
            } while (current != head);
        } else {
            result += "EMPTY";
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, but the original list does not seem to link circularly like you are expecting. Looks to me like your head is not referencing the first element in your list, but rather the last (`RABBIT`). And that your structure is `PURPLE` -> `HAPPY` -> `RABBIT` and `PURPLE` self references as it's parent while `RABBIT` has no child. Basically `PURPLE` <- `PURPLE` <-> `HAPPY` <-> `RABBIT`  -> `null`

Comment: Good point. Upon further investigation, I realized that I'm dealing with a circular doubly linked list, so I'm guessing I'll have to change my approach somewhat.

Comment: I do not see any problem with your code. The problem is with `head` which you should print before `if (current != null)` for debugging. Most likely it is having the value, `Rabbit`.

Answer (score 0):

Use descendingIterator

```
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add("Purple");
    list.add("Happy");
    list.add("Rabbit");
    for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.descendingIterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        String next =  iterator.next();
        System.out.println("next = " + next);
    }
```